# Surgical techniques for physical makeover

Tags: science-based, society, science-fiction

In the world the elite tends to be tall. The commoners tend be much shorter two or more feet shorter. https://www.hss.edu/conditions_limb-lengthening-overview.asp talks about several inches of lengthening on patients. In the world gangs recruit those who agree to infiltrate the elite. They have secret insider sponsors.
Also the elite have been improved through genetic modification. They received better nutrition and physical training akin to Sparta.
The recruits are young women. They undergo surgery for lengthening and physical improvement. **What are the surgical technologies to do that?**

The checks in the world are basically fitness and cognitive tests. Think of fitness tests as those in elite units of armed forces. I will look for reference later. Cognitive tests are just done in classrooms. Off course upper class citizens behave very differently from lower class ones. So the ultimate test is fitting in.

Comment: Size shouldn't matter much for most basic physical tests (Unless the elite are all national athletes... Which seems weird x) ), and not at all for mind ones. If they do make physical tests however, the women would likely have to wear special sport clothes, which means it's less likely you can hide surgery "imperfections" through loose clothing. Thus, in which conditions do they make these tests?

Comment: @Tortliena I updated the part about the tests

Comment: You link to an article about limb lengthening and then ask what the surgical technologies to do so are? Why not read the article, and, moreover, what does this have to do with worldbuilding?

Comment: The technology is not good enough for me. Did you read the whole question?

Comment: Are you asking us to brainstorm new surgical technologies for you? We're not a brainstorming site. If your world has future technologies for limb lengthening you need to establish how it works on your own. If you have a specific issue you'd like help with while brainstorming we're here to help you with that but asking us to make up things in your world isn't permitted here.

Comment: I have, yes, multiple times. I don't see anywhere that that's what you take away from it, and that you're asking for improved technology, which seems to be an unsuitable question for Worldbuilding. Besides, and again, what does this have to do with Worldbuilding in the first place?

Comment: "better nutrition and physical training akin to Sparta" - please read about the real Sparta rather than looking at comics and movies based on those comics.  Although it is true that the 6% of spartiates had much better nutrition than the other 94% of the population due to their brutal exploitation of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Leg transplants.**

Very tall elites are captured and humanely relieved of their legs.  These legs are then transplanted onto the young women, making them tall.  This leaves scars which are concealed with artful plastic surgery and tattoos.  The young women must take antirejection medicine but these pills are disguised as herbal supplements and actually contain some herbal supplement too in case someone tests them.

The legs removed from these short young women are not wasted but are transplanted onto the now less tall elites; it would be a waste to throw them out and the elites are grateful to wake up with some kind of legs.  Plus now those elites get to learn how the other half lives!

The elites who have had their legs taken might complain to the police but no-one will listen to them now that they are short.